# Compiling and running Java code - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I tried to compile some code written in Java and I used the command:

```
javac Code.java
java Code.java
```

and I got following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Code/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Code.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: Code.java. Program will exit.
```

I would be thankful for your advice.

Comment: You should be running `javac Code.java` and then `java Code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of compiling java code in your case is

```
javac Code.java
```

and then run using

```
java Code
```